# Advice on the correct use of ngModel

Tags: angularjs

I' new to AngularJS and have a following ambiguity with usage of ngModel. I want to give to the user possibility to generate unlimited number of "name": "value" pairs.  So I generating div with ng-repeat for every element from pair. Here is my html:

```
<div ng-app>

    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
         <input type="button" value="+" ng-click="addNewRow();"/>
        <div ng-repeat="a in range(itemsNumber)"><input type="text" name="key"/> : <input type="text" name="value"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.itemsNumber = 1;
    $scope.range = function() {
        return new Array($scope.itemsNumber);
    };

    $scope.addNewRow = function () {
        $scope.itemsNumber++;
    }
};
```

Here is working js fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/zono/RCW2k/
I want to have model for this generating items but not sure how to do it.

I would appreciate any ideas and tips.

Best regards.

Edit:

I have create other solution. It can be viewed in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zono/RCW2k/8/
But is this solution is good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RCW2k/13/

#### You should just create an array on the scope and it's also your model:

**controller:**

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.items = [{key:"hello",value:"world"}]

    $scope.addNewRow = function () {
        $scope.items.push({key:"",value:""});
    }
};
```

**html:**

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
     <input type="button" value="+" ng-click="addNewRow();"/>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="text" name="key" ng-model="item.key"/> : 
        <input type="text" name="value" ng-model="item.value"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. I'm coming to similar solution. Best regards!